# Prevent google from analyzing assets directory for mobile compatibility

Tags: php, laravel, google-search-console

How to **prevent Bots** from crawling the **assets folder** with all pictures and other media inside ?

I did it before with my **robot.txt** but Google **Web Master Tools** told me that there was 404 Response over the assets/img assets/videos etc.. Url.

So how to do this great ?
How to tell to google that my assets directory mustn't be take in count when it tests my website for mobile compatibility..

This is my robot.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: 
Disallow: /app
Disallow: /bootstrap
Disallow: /database
Disallow: /packages
Disallow: /vendor
Disallow: /public
Disallow: /assets
Disallow: /cdn-cgi
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can we see your robots.txt file as it stands? Seems to be you just need to add a rule for the `/assets/` folder. The 404 may be due to broken links on this site - we can't tell you what needs fixing if we don't know what they are.

Comment: "How to block a directory from being crawled but without prevent pictures from being on [Google Images]" - that's likely not possible. Google Images needs a crawler index to know what images to show (and it is likely to use the standard GoogleBot rather than running its own).

Comment: I know, it's more like, "how to tell to google that the img folder is not to take in count when it tests my website for mobile compatibility"...